# Cppcheck inline suppression not working

Tags: cppcheck

Example code:

```
class Foo {
    // cppcheck-suppress noExplicitConstructor
    Foo(int foo) { }
}
```

Cppcheck call:

```
$ cppcheck.exe --enable=all foo.cpp
Checking foo.cpp...
[foo.cpp:3]: (style) Class 'Foo' has a constructor with 1 argument that is not explicit.
```

How can I suppress this error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This way:

```
class Foo {     
// cppcheck-suppress  noExplicitConstructor     
 Foo(int foo) { } 
};
```

It requires `--inline-suppr` as command line argument.

Comment: Or setting the switch *Enable inline suppressions* in the GUI version.